# What is class.prototype and what is the merit of use it

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, jestjs, prototype

I've found folloing sample in which As if `Service` class has `prototype` property.

①Service is not instansiated, why `Service = new Service()` didn't need ?

②`console.log(Service.prototype` returned `{}`,what is this object ? What is the merit to manipulate this?

```
beforeEach(async ()=>{
    jest.spyOn(Service.prototype, 'execute')
})
```

I am totally novice to this concept, if someone has opinion will you please let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this does is that whenever `.execute(...)` is called on *any* `Service` instance, your spying thingy would fire.

It doesn't need `new Service()` because it's not working on a single service instance, it is working on the class itself.

It works by replacing `Service.prototype.execute` with a wrapper function that logs the call and then calls the original function, something like this:

```js
const oldExecute = Service.prototype.execute
Service.prototype.execute = function (...args) {
  console.log('execute called!', args)
  return oldExecute.call(this, ...args)
}
```

Class methods are nothing other than properties on the class' prototype, so if you have `class Test { hello (x) { return x * 2 } }` and you do `console.log(Test.prototype.hello)`, it will log the method `hello (x) { return x * 2 }`, and if you do `testInstance.hello(123)` it essentially then calls `Test.prototype.hello.call(testInstance, 123)`, i.e. it calls the function `Test.prototype.hello` with `testInstance` as `this`.

And the `{}` that you see is not everything there is, because the methods are by default non-enumerable. You should look at it in a debugger that also shows non-enumerable properties. Then you will see the class' methods there:

[image]

This is also the reason why when referring to the "full name" of a class method, often `ClassName.prototype.methodName` is used, because that's actually how you would get that method itself without referring to a particular class instance (to make use of it, you would have to call it with its `this` set to some instance, though, like what I did with `.call` above). For example, the `slice` function that exists on `Array` (when you write `[1, 2, 3].slice(1)` for instance) is referred to as [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) (in other languages this would be called `Array::slice`, `Array#slice` or the like). Sometimes you will also see people talking about `Array.slice` but that's technically not correct because `slice` is not a static method and doesn't exists on `Array` itself (unlike, for example, [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)).

---

Further reading:

- [MDN: Object prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes)
- [MDN: Classes in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Classes_in_JavaScript)
- [MDN: Docs for `Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) (to understand the examples)
- [Jest docs for `spyOn`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname)